# automatic width of a div inside a div container

Tags: html, css

I have a design question.
I need to create a progress bar for a video player.
I have a div container (id *videoManager*) with all the div about the PLAY, the STOP, the progress bar, the VOLUME, other buttons, all one beside the other (floating left).

i would like the div of the progress bar (id *playerSlider*) resizes depending on the remained space. i wrote down this code, but if use "width: 100%;" for this div, it doesn't get the remained space, but the 100% of the container. 
suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div id="videoManager">
  <div id="playpauseCommand">Play</div>
  <div id="stopCommand">Stop</div>
  <div id="playerSlider">
    <div id="objSlider"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="timeElement">10:12:12</div>
  <div id="volumeSlider"></div>
  <div id="displayCommand">Command</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#videoManager{
   margin-top: 30px;
   width: 980px;
   height: 44px;
   background: transparent url('bg.jpg') center center repeat-x;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
}
   div#playpauseCommand, div#stopCommand{
      width: 44px;
      height: 44px;
      float: left;
      border-right: 2px solid #555;
   }
   div#playerSlider{
      float:left;
      height: 44px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
   }
      div#objectSlider{
         float: left;
         clear: left;
         width: 100%;
      }
   div#timeElement{
      float: left;
      height: 44px;
      width: 80px;
      border-right: 2px solid #555;
   }
   div#volumeSlider{
      float: left;
      height: 44px;
      width: 180px;
      border-right: 2px solid #555;
   }
   div#displayCommand{
      float: left;
      height: 44px;
      width: 70px;
      border-right: 2px solid #555;
   }
```

and this is a link [to my site](http://www.alessandrorabitti.eu/video/indexf.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this css code, not sure if this is exactly what you want though:

```
div#videoManager{
margin-top: 30px;
width: 980px;
height: 44px;
background: transparent url('bg.jpg') center center repeat-x;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
}
div#playpauseCommand, div#stopCommand{
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
}
div#playerSlider{
  float:left;
  height: 44px;
  width: 53%;
  padding: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
 position:absolute;
 left:178px;
}
 div#objectSlider{
     float: left;
     clear: left;
     width: 100%;
  }
div#timeElement{
  float: left;
  height: 44px;
  width: 80px;
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
}
div#volumeSlider{
  float: right;
  height: 44px;
  width: 180px;
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
}
div#displayCommand{
  float: right;
  height: 34px;
   width: 70px;
 top:10px;
  border-right: 2px solid #555;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: it's not exactly what i need. the playerSlider div needs to fit the remained space, entirely